# How to catch widget placement in Android

Tags: java, android, widget

I need handler which catches widget placement. Is there something like that?

I tried `onAppWidgetOptionsChanged()`but not working as I need.

Comment: Please add a code here what u exactly do in your Code. @robineki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    @Override
public void onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId, Bundle newOptions) {
    super.onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId, newOptions);
    try {
            //open selection
            Intent intn = new Intent (context, DialogSelect.class);
            intn.setFlags (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intn);
    } catch (Exception e) {Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
    updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
}
```

Override method do not working